# Does it ever make sense to scale a velocity by the ratio of two velocities?

Tags: calculus, queueing-theory

I have a problem where a car enters a tunnel at one rate, and leaves the tunnel at another.

$$ v_{enter}$$
$$ v_{exit}$$

The car travels at some rate while its in the tunnel before it leaves.

$$v_{inside}$$

I was wondering, if I wanted to calculate the number of cars in the tunnel at any point in time, if the following equation would be correct:

$$\frac{d[number of cars]}{dt} = v_{enter} - v_{exit} \times \frac{v_{exit}}{v_{inside}}$$

Comment: Consider a simpler problem: there's an underground parking garage midway along the tunnel, and every car that goes in parks there. You can still talk about $da/dt,$ where $a$ is the total number of cars in the tunnel and/or garage. You will get the same $da/dt$ if a car enters the tunnel at $10$ km/h every $2$ seconds, or $120$ km/h every $2$ seconds: $da/dt = 1/2.$ So you really need some different information than what you have given.

Answer (score 0):

You don't care about the speed that the cars travel, you just care about the rate of cars passing a given point.  If the rate of entry is $r_{entry}$ and the rate of exit is $r_{exit}$ you have $$\frac{d[number of cars]}{dt} = r_{enter} - r_{exit}$$

Comment: Would it be possible to determine the positions of the cars, either waiting to leave or travelling on their way to leave given that I know the velocity they travel at inside the tunnel?